# useMutation loader for S3 image upload w/ Apollo react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client

When I upload an image to S3 it takes a while to return the file from AWS. When trying to use the "loading" property from apollo/react-hooks it doesn't take into consideration the file upload and always returns true before the image location has actually returned

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { UPLOAD_FILE } from "../../queries";
const [uploadFile, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(UPLOAD_FILE);

  if (loading) {
    alert(loading)
  } else {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data, 'DATA');
      values.image  = data
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add createUploadLink in ApolloCient for file upload?

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';


const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: GRAPHQL_URI,
  headers: {
    'keep-alive': 'true',
  },
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: GRAPHQL_URI,
  link: ApolloLink.from([errLink, uploadLink, link]),
  ...
});
```